# Enlarge image when imageview inside a scrollview is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an app that implements Horizontal gallery. I am able to display the image thumbnails. Now what I need to do is to enlarge the image when it is tapped. I am using [EMNotificationPopup](https://github.com/ennioma/EMNotificationPopup) to display the enlarged image. Here's what I have so far:

This snippet is in my viewdidload:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap;
UIImageView * imageview; 

singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
singleTap.delegate = self;

[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self coreManagementWithPosition:EMNotificationPopupPositionCenter andType:EMNotificationPopupBig];
}

- (void) coreManagementWithPosition: (EMNotificationPopupPosition) position andType:(EMNotificationPopupType) notificationPopupType {
    if (_notificationPopup.isVisible) {
        [_notificationPopup dismissWithAnimation:YES];
        _notificationPopup = NULL;
    } else {
        _notificationPopup = [[EMNotificationPopup alloc] initWithType:notificationPopupType enterDirection:EMNotificationPopupToDown exitDirection:EMNotificationPopupToLeft popupPosition:position];
        _notificationPopup.delegate = self;

        _notificationPopup.title = @"Sorry for this Alert message :)";
        _notificationPopup.subtitle = @"Awesome message :)";
        _notificationPopup.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_image"];

        if (notificationPopupType == EMNotificationPopupBigButton)
            _notificationPopup.actionTitle = @"OK";

        [_notificationPopup show];
    }
}
```

My issue here is **handleImageTap** is not being initialised/called. How can enable the user interaction for imageview.

Comment: Are you implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`?

Comment: Has `imageview` been initialized already when you add the gesture recognizer?

Comment: @TheSD yes, i am implementing UIGestureRecognizerDelegate..handleImageTap is still not called.

Comment: @Stonz2 hey, i initialised imageview (imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init] still the same.. -_-

Comment: I have checked your code and its working fine inside a scroll view. The only way its not working is by disabling user interaction for scroll view.

Comment: @user1988 still not working.. -_-